# javascript traffic light automation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my traffic light sequence automated with a 3 second timer rather than changing when a button is pressed. here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<img id="light" src="X:/A452/Traffic lights/Assets/traffic-lights-green.jpg">

<button onclick=Green() id="button">
Change!</button>

</body>

<script>

var Green = function() {
    document.getElementById('light').src='X:/A452/Traffic lights/Assets/traffic-lights-green.jpg';
    document.getElementById( "button" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Amber();" );
}

var Amber = function() {
    document.getElementById('light').src='X:/A452/Traffic lights/Assets/traffic-lights-amber.jpg';
    document.getElementById( "button" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Red();" );
}

var Red = function() {
    document.getElementById('light').src='X:/A452/Traffic lights/Assets/traffic-light-red.jpg';
    document.getElementById( "button" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: AmberTwo();" );
}

var AmberTwo = function() {
    document.getElementById('light').src='X:/A452/Traffic lights/Assets/traffic-lights-amber.jpg';
    document.getElementById( "button" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Green();" );
}

</script>

</html>
```

I cannot figure out how I set the timer for the picture to change and also what will activate the different functions already specified in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your code and list what issues you are having with it so we can help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: he wants to automate the color change.

Comment: Seems like the styling should be defined as CSS classes.  Also, where is your function for changing the lights?

Comment: @maniak1982 its right there in the onClick event of button

Comment: First of all, don't attach event handlers by setting the "onClick" attribute, especially not to a `javascript:` schemed URL (which is only required for an `href` attribute). `document.getElementById( "button" ).onclick = Green;` is cleaner. Secondly, your server doesn't know what "X:/" is, since it's likely a mapped network drive or local drive.

Comment: You should definitely check the site guidelines for submitting questions http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Here is something which you can capitalize on https://jsfiddle.net/1vdhyyLu/ Automate part is ok, But on what basis will you change the signal?? is it time based? or some other event based etc etc.. you need to be more clear with your question. right now I have created a example which changes the light every second.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us more information about your problem.

Don't attach event handlers by setting the "onClick" attribute, not to a javascript: schemed URL (which is only required for an href attribute). 
 
`document.getElementById( "button" ).onclick = Green;` is cleaner. 
Secondly, your server doesn't know what `"X:/"` is, since it's likely a mapped network drive or local drive.

@Mike McCaughan